# template schema importing all the files in a folder

Tags: google-deployment-manager

This a section in a schema file

```
   imports:
    - path: configs/folder1/resources/gcpresource/test/*
```

I am trying to import all the files in a folder using the template's schema file.
I know that this does not work.

My question is,
what is a better way to import all the files using * or something that's suitable so that deployment manager can import all of the files in a folder without having to explicitly specify them ?

Comment: Template name and paths must end with a file extension. This is not possible to import all the files together at this time. I would suggest you to file a feature request in our public [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: @Milad is there any workaround for this? What is it doing when it imports files? How can that be done programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You could do so in python if they are all yaml config files

```
# my-template.yaml
imports:
- path: omni-importer.py
```

And in the `middleware-like` python template do something like:

```
# omni-importer.py
import yaml
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
def generate_config(ctx):
  mypath = ctx.properties['path']
  files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f)) and f.endswith('yaml')]
  yamls = map(lambda f: yaml.load(open('test.txt')['resources']), files)
  return {
    'resources': yamls,
  }
```

This is not working code, but rather a proof of concept